Put a gate in front of a wave in Quantikz
I'm trying to make a circuit in quantiks that represents an arbitrary sized gate
\begin{quantikz}[background color=black!5!white]
&\gate[5]{H^{\otimes n}} &\swap{4} & \\
& & & \\
\wave &&&\\
& & & \\ 
& & \targX{} &
\end{quantikz}

It renders with the gate behind the wave like this

Any suggestions on how to fix it?
